# multiple comboboxes in R using tcltk

Tags: r, tk-toolkit, combobox

I have been trying to define multiple combo boxes in R using the tcltk package but to no avail.  I am using the below code.  My inspiration was [here](http://bioinf.wehi.edu.au/~wettenhall/RTclTkExamples/DropDown.html), however I can't seem to just *label* them comboBox1, comboBox2, etc... so I decided to try and set their output values into a vector... but their output values don't make any sense to me... any ideas out there?

many thanks

```
require(tcltk)
tclRequire("BWidget")
tt <- tktoplevel()
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="What's your favorite fruits?"))
fruit <- c("Apple","Orange","Banana","Pear")
num <- c(0:3)
num.fruit <- cbind(num, fruit)
#####1st box
comboBox <- tkwidget(tt,"ComboBox",editable=FALSE,values=num.fruit[,2])
tkgrid(comboBox)
Cbox1<- comboBox
tkfocus(tt)

######2nd box

comboBox <- tkwidget(tt,"ComboBox",editable=FALSE,values=num.fruit[,2])
tkgrid(comboBox)
Cbox2 <- comboBox
###

##preliminary wrap-ip to pass to OnOK function
pref1 <- tcl(Cbox1,"getvalue")
pref2 <- tcl(Cbox2,"getvalue")

  Prefs <- c(pref1,pref2)
######action on OK button
OnOK <- function()
{
    fruitChoice <- fruits[as.numeric(tclvalue(tcl(Prefs,"getvalue")))+1]

    tkdestroy(tt)
    msg <- paste("Good choice! ",fruitChoice,"s are delicious!",sep="")
    tkmessageBox(title="Fruit Choice",message=msg)

}
OK.but <-tkbutton(tt,text="   OK   ",command=OnOK)
tkgrid(OK.but)
tkfocus(tt)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use `ttkcombobox`?

```
require(tcltk)
tt <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.title(tt, "Fruits!")
tkwm.geometry(tt, "200x150+300+300") 

onOK <- function()
    {
    fav <- tclvalue(favFruit)
    worst <- tclvalue(worstFruit)

    if (fav != "Choose one")
        tkmessageBox(title="Favorite fruit", message = paste("Your favorite fruit is", fav))
    if (worst != "Choose one")
        tkmessageBox(title="Worst fruit", message = paste("The fruit you like the least is", worst))

    if (fav == "Choose one" & worst == "Choose one")
        tkmessageBox(title="Well...", message = "Select a fruit!")
    }

label1 <- tklabel(tt, text="What's your favorite fruit?")
label2 <- tklabel(tt, text="What fruit you like the least?")

fruits <- c("Choose one", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Pear")
# Default selections for the two combo boxes
favFruit <- tclVar("Choose one")
worstFruit <- tclVar("Choose one")

# 1st box
combo.1 <- ttkcombobox(tt, values=fruits, textvariable=favFruit, state="readonly") 
# 2nd box
combo.2 <- ttkcombobox(tt, values=fruits, textvariable=worstFruit, state="readonly") 
# If you need to do something when the user changes selection just use
# tkbind(combo.1, "<<ComboboxSelected>>", functionname)

OK.but <- tkbutton(tt,text="   OK   ", command = onOK)

tkpack(label1, combo.1)
tkpack(label2, combo.2)
tkpack(OK.but)

tkfocus(tt)
```

PS: personally, I abandoned `tcltk` in favour of `RGtk2`, much more flexible in my opinion and you can design interfaces visually using Glade Interface Designer

Comment: Thank you @nico that was exactly what I needed for a similar project.  I wish the tcltk/2 packages had great documentation somewhere, but if there is I haven't found it.  Worse even, I have found several examples online that just plain didn't work.  I wish I would have found this several hours ago!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get too involved with tcltk, you might find gWidgets easier to work with.

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk") ## or RGtk2 or Qt

w <- gwindow("Multiple comboboxes")
tbl <- glayout(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)

fruit <- c("Apple","Orange","Banana","Pear")


tbl[1,1] <- "Favorite fuits"
tbl[1,2] <- (cb1 <- gcombobox(fruit, cont=tbl))

tbl[2,1] <- "Other fruit?"
tbl[2,2] <- (cb2 <- gcombobox(fruit, cont=tbl))

tbl[3,2] <- (b <- gbutton("Ok", cont=tbl))

addHandlerClicked(b, handler=function(h,...) {
  cat(sprintf("You picked %s and %s\n", svalue(cb1), svalue(cb2)))
})
```

Comment: this is what I want to do, is put the combobox value into a vector and do stuff with that.  But I can't seem to get addHandlerClicked to work using RGtk2 or tcltk or Qt

Comment: **Edit:  I got it to work using: 
install.packages("gWidgetsRGtk2", dep=TRUE)

found at this amazing documentation site: http://user2007.org/program/presentations/verzani-1.pdf

Comment: The Qt toolkit implementation is on r-forge: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=761. It is still being developed, but looks much better than the tcltk version.