# how to get the selected value of drop down list using r

Tags: r, combobox

I have data as df, with 4 variable(long, lat, date, cluster) and I want to build GUI that can plot a selected cluster. For selected cluster I used drop down list, but how can I get the selected value of drop down list? for example

> a<- unique(data$cluster)
>
> a
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

and when I choose 5, I want to add that selected value to new variable

```
require(tcltk)
tclRequire("BWidget")

tt <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.title(tt,"Test GUI")
tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text="Test label"))
ttframe<-tkframe(tt,relief="groove",borderwidth=2)

z<-unique(data$cluster)

comboBox<-tkwidget(ttframe,"ComboBox",editable=FALSE,values=z)
tkgrid(comboBox)
tkgrid(ttframe)

tkgrid(tklabel(tt,text=""))
tkfocus(tt)
```

using addhandlerchange() ?? but how? where I can get some reference or example

well solved by myself hehe, the issues like this [same topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482513/multiple-comboboxes-in-r-using-tcltk)
and here the code

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk") ## or RGtk2 or Qt

w <- gwindow("Clustering")
tbl <- glayout(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)

cluster<- unique(data$cluster)

tbl[1,1] <- "Cluster"
tbl[1,2] <- (cb1 <- gcombobox(cluster, cont=tbl))

tbl[1,3] <- (b <- gbutton("Ok", cont=tbl))

addHandlerClicked(b, handler=function(h,...) {
  cluster_pilihan <- svalue(cb1)
  assign("cluster_pilihan", cluster_pilihan, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
```

Comment: but it still need to click the button, can someone improve my answer?

Comment: first of all, you shouldn't post this into 'gtk tags'. But anyway, in 'gtk', 'combobox' has 'changed' signal, which catch the signal if the drop down being hover by mouse. Your widget should have the implementation

Comment: You can can use `addHandlerChanged` on the combobox instead of `addHandlerClicked` on the button. Same handler. This will be called when the user selects a value -- no button needed. Your same handler should work. You might want to make an empty choice initially, as otherwise it can be confusing. Just pass in `selected=-1` for that.