# combobox example: tk2list.configure could not be found

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am following **A tk2combobox example** from **R tk2widgets** [examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tcltk2/versions/1.2-11/topics/tk2widgets).

Executing these lines

```
    library(tcltk2) 
    tt2 <- tktoplevel()
    cb <- tk2combobox(tt2)
    tkgrid(cb)
    ## Fill the combobox list 
    fruits <- c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana") 
    tk2list.set(tt2, fruits)
```

Fails with this message

> Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") :
>   [tcl] bad command "list": must be bbox, cget, configure, current,
>   delete, get, icursor, identify, index, insert, instate, selection,
>   state, set, validate, or xview.

I check my tcl version `echo 'puts $tcl_version;exit 0' | tclsh`
 and get this answer:

> 8.6

It seems to be that I am missing some library.

Is it?

Comment: That error is coming from the combobox instance (it's precisely characteristic of it). I've no idea why the R part of the code (the `tcltk2` library) might be asking for the `list` method to be called on it, but since comboboxes have _never_ supported that method, it's a bug on the R side to even ask for it.

Comment: @DonalFellows , thank you for your kind answer!
Now it is clear to me.
I found a way to build combobox in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3482697